# Startup error writing to to /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rab04.log

Tags: rabbitmq

Rabbitmq with erlang-base-hipe installed on Ubuntu 14.04 starts fine, but logs several of these messages in the /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log file

```
Error: function_clause
Stack trace: [{error_logger_file_h,write_event,
              [{<0.4819.0>,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rab04.log",[]},
               {info_msg,<0.31.0>,
                   {<0.2.0>,"HiPE in use: compiled ~B modules in ~Bs.~n",
                    "9\e"}}],
              [{file,"error_logger_file_h.erl"},{line,114}]},
          {error_logger_file_h,handle_event,2,
              [{file,"error_logger_file_h.erl"},{line,79}]},
          {rabbit_error_logger_file_h,safe_handle_event,3,[]},
          {gen_event,server_update,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,538}]},
          {gen_event,server_notify,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,520}]},
          {gen_event,server_notify,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,522}]},
          {gen_event,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,261}]},
          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]
```

RabbitMQ works fine, however, we no longer get information written to the error log file.

The change is that we installed  erlang-base-hipe and modified /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config with

```
   {hipe_compile, true}
```

The permissions on /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rab04.log are 644 and owned by the user and group rabbitmq which is the user configured for the rabbitmq service.

Suggestions on how to debug and or repair this problem are appreciated.

Comment: It might be related with using Erlang 18.1. See https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/324

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ are you using?

Comment: We are using the following. RabbitMQ 3.5.4-1 and erlang-base-hipe 1:18.1.

Comment: I was mistaken. The problem is repeatable when using RabbitMQ 3.5.5 + Erlang 1:18.1. The problem does not occur when using RabbitMQ 3.5.4 + Erlang 1:18.1.

Comment: If I start 3.5.4 using Erlang 18.1 I get the same errors. The problem is that the error logger module in Erlang has a breaking change on how its internal state is handled. See the github issue I've pointed above for more details.

Also please in the future ask this kind of questions on our mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users